# Exemption for Sports beta

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I just found out on Web Applications Meta that a new threshold limit have been enforced, concerning the review queue:

[Propose a privilege to sit in the 500 reputation mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186373/propose-a-privilege-to-sit-in-the-500-reputation-mark)

I propose to apply for an exemption for Sports beta !! I was getting the hang of it, here on Sports beta, but it will limit the number of users that review considerably, especially on a low votings site like Sports beta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be for graduated sites. Rep thresholds are lower on all beta sites across the board.

Comment: Well, I've lost mine....screenshot chat and my review history.

Comment: yes, they've recently raised it from what it was (75 maybe?) to 350. and from 125 on graduated sites to 500.

Comment: I think it happened only today.....

Comment: yeah, these things happen suddenly and with little to no notice (Specially if you don't watch MSO like a hawk)

Comment: I will accept your answer, even though it ignores my question, because the threshold limits for beta sites are lower.